# C# generic handler query string parameters in array

Tags: c#, arrays, datatables, ashx

I have a query string which is in array format, and im trying to figure out how I would access  the sub elements using Context.Request

heres an example of my query string params

```
QueryString

    draw                          1
    search[value]                 test
```

and so in my C# generic handler (ashx) code I modeled after something i would do in PHP or Coldfusion I did the following

```
if (context.Request["search"]["value"] != "") {
 for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++) ...
}
```

i get the following error

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.this[int]'
>   has some invalid arguments

Any idea how i write this piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i ended up accessing the query string arrays

```
var searchString = context.Request["search[value]"];

var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["order[0][column]"]);
var sortDirection = context.Request["order[0][dir]"]; // asc or desc
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible (at least in that way as you expect it), but you still can pass array(but simply array, not dictionary) from your query string (e.g. `search=test&search=test1`) and server side you can receive these values like so:

```
string[] searches = context.Request.Form.GetValues("search");
//searches[0] = "test"
//searches[1] = "test1"
```

**Update 1.**

And if you still need it be something similar to dictionary you can make a workaround. First of all you need your query string in a different way like (`|` will act as a delimiter):

```
search=value|test&search=value1|test1
```

and then server-side you will be able to do things like that:

```
var value1Value = context.Request.Form.GetValues("search")
.ToList()
.Select(x => x.Split("|"))
.Where(x => x[0] == "value1")
.Select(x => x[1])
.FirstOrDefault(); //test1
```

(getting exact value)

```
foreach (var keyValue in context.Request.Form.GetValues("search").ToList().Select(x => x.Split("|")))
{
    //keyValue[0] = value and value1
    //keyValue[1] = test and test1
}
```

(iterating through all values)

Comment: well its not an iterative querystring, at least this one is not (there are others) but in this case, the query string param is search['value'] the actual word value

Comment: thank you, this was helpful, but i was looking for what i posted